# Fourier transform double integration

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

Let $f(t)$ be a generic integrable function (where $t$ is time).
Let $F(\omega)$ be its Fourier transform, and $F^{-1}(t)$ its inverse transform.

Suppose every continuity and integrability condition is met. It is legit to say $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(\omega) e^{2i\pi\omega t} d\omega dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F^{-1}(t) dt$ ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$F(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{i2\pi\omega t}\,dt \tag 1$$

and

$$f(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(\omega)e^{-i2\pi\omega t}\,d\omega \tag 2$$

From $(1)$ we find

$$F(0)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\,dt $$

If we integrate $(2)$, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\,dt&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(\omega)e^{-i2\pi\omega t}\,d\omega \,dt\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(\omega)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i2\pi\omega t} \,dt\,d\omega\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(\omega)\delta(\omega)\,d\omega\\\\
&=F(0)
\end{align}$$

as expected.

Comment: Fine! Many thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure.